# pandas dataframe removing following row based on value in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

simple question but I have not been able to find anything on this. I have the following dataframe, and hope to accomplish the following:

where Roll = 1 in our dataframe, I want to delete the next row, and only that one row. Keep in mind that many rows for Roll will be 0 but only a few need to be removed specifically rows where the preceding row for Roll = 1

```
Date    Close    Open    Roll
1       500      499     0
2       502      502     0
3       500      499     0
4       500      499     1
5       501      502     0 (delete this row)
6       506      506     0
7       509      508     0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a boolean mask using [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html#pandas.Series.shift) that tests whether the previous row contains 1 or not:

```
In [24]:
df[df['Roll'].shift() != 1]

Out[24]:
   Date  Close  Open  Roll
0     1    500   499     0
1     2    502   502     0
2     3    500   499     0
3     4    500   499     1
5     6    506   506     0
6     7    509   508     0
```

the boolean mask looks like this:

```
In [25]:
df['Roll'].shift() != 1

Out[25]:
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5     True
6     True
Name: Roll, dtype: bool
```

Comment: I don't understand, that's what the first part of my answer demonstrates

Comment: all good thanks EdChum! Also, can you point me in the direction on anything that will explain shift() in detail? I have a hard time finding detailed info on it, as it looks so simple but it works great. appreciate it

Comment: The api [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html#pandas.Series.shift) has a little information

Comment: correct me if im wrong, but is the logic here that the code runs through the Roll series by looking at True or False for Roll = 1, and then based on an outcome being False it shifts down the entire row, therefore eliminating it? I guess I am trying to wrap my head around how such a simple piece of code can do all that.

Comment: It shifts the the series by a single row, there is no rolling as it will introduce a `NaN` value at the first row

Comment: sorry for the million questions but I just want to make sure I understand something before I blindly use it. How does the code know where to shift, it doesn't look intuitive when we have "...shift() != 1"

Comment: I call `shift` on the column so `df['Roll'].shift()` will move the rows down by one, you can see this when you try it yourself